# Running self-hosted (Windows Service) ServiceStack http listener on Port 80 SxS IIS

Tags: servicestack

We're re-writing our services from ASMX -> RESTful using ServiceStack so there's a short term need to keep IIS and classic services running on port 80.  Also, some of our customers host more than one web app (e.g. company intranet) under IIS listening on port 80.

My application needs to be distributed to hundreds of customers, so I'd like to move away from the IIS dependency in the interest of making my deployment of updates simpler - if possible.  We also have many customers who have setup special forwarding in their routers for port 80, so listening on a different port for SS services would cause a lot of deployment pain - not to mention most firewalls are more lenient with port 80 traffic.

I have two possible related issues:
1. When I can get SS to fire up on port 80, I get "`handler not found`" for routes that would otherwise work on another port.
2. While debugging (start / debug / stop / restart), eventually a listener registration appears to "stick" and I end up getting:

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Failed to listen on prefix 'http://*:80/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpListenerBase.Start(String urlBase) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\WebHost.Endpoints\Support\HttpListenerBase.cs:line 122
   at FieldCommService.FieldCommService.ConfigureServices() in e:\Development\Source\Hg\fieldcomm\src\Services\FieldCommService\FieldCommService.cs:line 305
   at FieldCommService.FieldCommService.Startup() in e:\Development\Source\Hg\fieldcomm\src\Services\FieldCommService\FieldCommService.cs:line 84
```

I won't rule out hosting the service under IIS as a solution, I just prefer not to take on/continue to take on the configuration and deployment pain IIS comes with.

I have two questions:
1. Is listening on :80 as a self hosted service possible [with AppHostHttpListenerBase]?
2. In the intellisense for AppHostHttpListenerBase, it's noted that this class is designed to allow listening on port 80 next to IIS, but that "admin user privileges" are required.  What does this imply under Windows running as a Service?  An identity belonging to the Administrators group?  Or simply "Local System"?

Comment: Only different ports (i.e. not custompaths) are supported with HttpListener host. File an issue if you want to see support for this (so you can track feature and we can measure demand)

Comment: when you say "custompaths" are you implying this is the same root issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476685/configure-servicestack-base-uri/11476965#11476965 - i.e., they might both be addressed by adding the same core piece of functionality?

Comment: Yep thought it looked familiar :) is this not the same issue?

Comment: (Obviously I can't speak to the technical similarity like you can but...) No, this has to do with simply listening on :80 as a self-hosted service.  The other question was if it's possible to define a base route (e.g. http://myserver:8657/myapi with routes under /myapi, vs. this is simply can we listen on :80 and accept requests at http://myserver)

Comment: Note: Listening on ports < 1024 (like 80) require admin rights.

Comment: 2. In the intellisense for AppHostHttpListenerBase, it's noted that this class is designed to allow listening on port 80 next to IIS, but that "admin user privileges" are required. What does this imply under Windows running as a Service? An identity belonging to the Administrators group? Or simply "Local System"? :) - at the moment though, I cam simply running as a console app to debug on my local box w/o uac where i am an admin and I still get the above.